TestCafe usage with Docker - Socket Hang Up - Cannot establish one or more browser connections Errors
I am trying to run TestCafe tests inside docker container.
I am able to run my tests with npm run testrunner locally. Inside Docker container, I get different errors on different tries.
The errors I get are as follows:
With firefox:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage option:
...-tests  | Error: Cannot establish one or more browser connections.
...-tests  | 3 of 3 browser connections have not been established:
...-tests  | - firefox:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage
...-tests  | - firefox:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage
...-tests  | - firefox:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage
...-tests  | 
...-tests  | Hints:
...-tests  | - Increase the Browser Initialization Timeout if its value is too low (currently: 2 minutes for local browsers and 6 minutes for remote browsers). The timeout determines how long TestCafe waits for browsers to be ready.
...-tests  | - The error can also be caused by network issues or remote device failure. Make sure that your network connection is stable and you can reach the remote device.

With chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage option:
...-tests  | Error: Unable to open the "chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage" browser due to the following error:
...-tests  | 
...-tests  | Error: WebSocket connection closed
...-tests  |     at /app/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:94:35
...-tests  |     at Chrome._handleConnectionClose (/app/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:256:13)
...-tests  |     at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:243:22)
...-tests  |     at WebSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
...-tests  |     at WebSocket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
...-tests  |     at WebSocket.emitClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:246:10)
...-tests  |     at Socket.socketOnClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1148:15)
...-tests  |     at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
...-tests  |     at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
...-tests  |     at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12)
...-tests  |     at BrowserConnection._runBrowser (/app/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/connection/index.ts:291:32)

With chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage option and const testcafe = await createTestCafe({ experimentalProxyless: true }); initialization:
...-tests  | Error: Unable to open the "chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage" browser due to the following error:
...-tests  | 
...-tests  | Error: socket hang up
...-tests  |     at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:524:23)
...-tests  |     at Socket.emit (node:events:530:35)
...-tests  |     at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
...-tests  |     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
...-tests  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
...-tests  |     at BrowserConnection._runBrowser (/app/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/connection/index.ts:291:32)
...-tests  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Dockerfile
FROM testcafe/testcafe
USER root

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install --force --legacy-peer-deps --progress=false
COPY ./ ./
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD npm run testrunner

package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "cafe:prod:h:3": "npx testcafe 'firefox:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage' src/tests/masterdata",
    "testrunner": "node runner.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-ssm": "^3.535.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1582.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "downloads-folder": "^3.0.3"
  }
}

runner.js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

(async function () {
  const testcafe = await createTestCafe({ experimentalProxyless: true });
  try {
    const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
    const failed = await runner
      .src(['src/tests/masterdata'])
      .browsers('chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage')
      .concurrency(3)
      .run();

    console.log('Tests failed: ' + failed);
  } finally {
    await testcafe.close();
  }
})();

What do I need to run tests in Docker?
